# How to add custom CSS on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that has some predefined CSS. With this button i have created an action button and a textarea.

Whenever i write some CSS in textarea then it should be added to existing button's CSS when submitting this CSS by action button.

I tried this-

**jQuery-**

```
$(function(){
    $('.add').click(function(){
      var custom=$('.textarea').val();
        $('.button').css(custom);

    });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, How can i do this?

Is `iframe` Needed here?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vR9jG/1/)

Comment: Textarea value is string in your case you must to add Javascript object or want to add only 1 property ?

Comment: can you post a sample input ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$('.button').attr("style", custom);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vR9jG/2/)

Comment: Oh yes indeed, you can remove this. It's used for logging messages to the console.

Comment: @Manoz `console.log` is used for troubleshooting code - it outputs different values you specify to the console to see what's going on and when. It's not necessary in production!

Comment: @Stefan v., That was quick one. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

```
   $(function(){
        $('.add').click(function(){
          var custom=$('.textarea').val().split(',');        
             $('.button').css(custom[0],custom[1]);
        });
    });
```

pass in `background,red`in text area

Comment: Awesome and easy one. Taught me something new today +1.